# Delete row if the front row is the same in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe and want to delete row if the front row is the same.

My current code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("MyCSV.csv", ";")
df_2 = df.loc[:,['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]
for i in df_2.itertuples():
    if df_2[i] == df_2[i+1]:
    print(df)
```

I have this input dataframe:

[image: I have this dataframe]

And this is the output that I want:

[image: dataframe i want this dataframe]

Code for recreating the input dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [0,1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],
                   'A': [0.0] * 13, 
                   'B': [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.00000813,0.00000813,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.00000813,0.00000813], 
                   'C': [0.0000109,0.0000109,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0000109,0.0000109,0.0,0.0,0.0],
                   'D': [0.00000222,0.00000222,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.00000222,0.00000222,0.0,0.0,0.0]
                  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to do this as follows:

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df.loc[(df[cols].shift(-1) == df[cols]).all(1)]
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
time    A         B         C         D
   0  0.0  0.000000  0.000011  0.000002
   2  0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
   4  0.0  0.000008  0.000000  0.000000
   9  0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
  11  0.0  0.000000  0.000011  0.000002
  14  0.0  0.000008  0.000000  0.000000
```

Comment: don't make what i want

Comment: @meriem: I corrected the answer, it should work now.

Comment: @meriem: Did you manage to solve it? Consider accepting the answer if that is the case, see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: KeyError: "['A', 'B'] not in index" i have this error !

Comment: @meriem: Did you use `loc` when selecting the columns? Try: `df.loc[(df.loc[:, cols].shift(-1) == df.loc[:, cols]).all(1)]`.